# gradle fail to build application made on React Native

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

After upgrading my react native app to version 0.59.1 (ejected from expo) due new policy from Google all apps need to run on 64 cpu my gradle build is failing to build and the error is: **ERROR: Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1**.

I am not an Android developer and I dont know so much about android tools but this looks like I am missing something in build gradle files.

I checked the version of Android Gradle plugin version is 3.5.0 and gradle version says 5.4.1

This is how build.gradle (Project) looks like:

```
    buildscript {
      repositories {
        jcenter()
          google()
      }
      dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    //    old
    //    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.1'
    //    classpath 'de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:2.0.0'
    //    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
      }
    }

    allprojects {
      repositories {
        maven {
          url "$rootDir/maven"
        }
        maven {
          // We use a modified build of com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1. Explanation in maven-test/README
          url "$rootDir/maven-test"
        }
        jcenter()
        maven {
          // Local Maven repo containing AARs with JSC built for Android
          url "$rootDir/../js/node_modules/jsc-android/android"
        }
        flatDir {
          dirs 'libs'
          // dirs project(':expoview').file('libs')
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
          url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }

        // Want this last so that we never end up with a stale cache
        mavenLocal()
      }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
      delete rootProject.buildDir
    }

and build.gradle (app):

buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }

  dependencies {
//    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
//apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

repositories {
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
  flavorDimensions "default"
  compileSdkVersion 28
  buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.ferrometal12'
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName '0.1.1'
    ndk {
      abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
    }
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    // Deprecated. Used by net.openid:appauth
    manifestPlaceholders = [
      'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'host.exp.exponent'
    ]
  }
  dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize System.getenv("DISABLE_DEX_MAX_HEAP") ? null : "8g"
  }
  productFlavors {
    // Define separate dev and prod product flavors.
    dev {
      // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
      // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
      // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
      minSdkVersion 21
    }
    devRemoteKernel {
      minSdkVersion 21
    }
    dev19 {
      // For debugging / development on older SDK versions. Increases build
      // time so use 'dev' if not running on older SDKs.
      minSdkVersion 19
    }
    prod {
      // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
      minSdkVersion 19
    }
  }
  buildTypes {
    debug {
      debuggable true
    }
    release {
      minifyEnabled true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      zipAlignEnabled true
    }
  }
  signingConfigs {
    debug {
      storeFile file('../debug.keystore')
    }
  }
  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
  }
  packagingOptions {
    pickFirst "**"
  }
}

// Don't use modern jsc-android since it still has some critical bugs that
// crash applications when the string for the JS bundle is loaded and when
// locale-specific date functions are called.
// configurations.all {
//   resolutionStrategy {
//     force 'org.webkit:android-jsc:r216113'
//   }
// }


task exponentPrebuildStep(type: Exec) {
  workingDir '../'
  if (System.getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', '.\\detach-scripts\\prepare-detached-build.bat'
  } else {
    commandLine './detach-scripts/prepare-detached-build.sh'
  }
}
preBuild.dependsOn exponentPrebuildStep


dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

  // Our dependencies
//  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

  // Our dependencies from ExpoView
  // DON'T ADD ANYTHING HERE THAT ISN'T IN EXPOVIEW. ONLY COPY THINGS FROM EXPOVIEW TO HERE.
  implementation('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1') {
    force true // added force true due onesignal conflict, it wasnt before adding onesignal
  }
  implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
  compile('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.22.1') {
    exclude module: 'play-services-ads'
  }
  compileOnly 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:3.1.1'
  implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
  implementation 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
  implementation 'com.amplitude:android-sdk:2.9.2' // Be careful when upgrading! Upgrading might break experience scoping. Check with Jesse. See Analytics.resetAmplitudeDatabaseHelper
  implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
//  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
//  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.8.0'
//  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
//  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
//  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'
//  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.8.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Compiler:2.2.1'
  implementation "com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Core:2.2.1"
  implementation "com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow:2.2.1"
  implementation "com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.53.0.0"
  implementation "com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.53.0.0"
  debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta1'
  // debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta1'
  releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta1'
  implementation 'com.facebook.device.yearclass:yearclass:1.0.1'
  implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'
  implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.4@aar'
  implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
  implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.7'
  implementation 'com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.1'
  implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
  implementation 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.3.0'
  implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
  implementation 'net.openid:appauth:0.4.1'
  implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.0'
  implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.6.1'
  compile('io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.11') {
    transitive = false
  }

  implementation('com.android.support:exifinterface:26.0.1') {
    force true // added force true due onesignal conflict, it wasnt before adding onesignal
  }

  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.4.1'
  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.1'
  implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.9.0'

  // Testing
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
  // We use a modified build of com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1. Explanation in maven-test/README
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
  'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
  'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.1'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
  'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
  'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
  'com.azimolabs.conditionwatcher:conditionwatcher:0.2'



  compile('host.exp.exponent:expoview:26.0.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
  }

//  implementation project(path: ':expoview')
}

// This has to be down here for some reason
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And gradle.wrapper.properties looks as below:

```
#Sat Aug 31 19:13:53 EEST 2019
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
#distributionUrl=\
#  https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-rc-1-all.zip
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Please let me know if you need more details!